# Glassfish server stack traces not clickable in Eclipse WTP

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, m2e, eclipse-wtp

Other servers (e.g. TomEE) produce clickable stacktraces.
GF output is being colored, but stacktraces are not navigable.

The stacktraces are clickable when I load the project into Netbeans.

The enviroment is Ubuntu/KDE/x64; Eclipse Kepler; GF 4.0

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

We have reproduced the problem and filed a bug on GlassFish Tools. You can monitor for future releases on OEPE forum.

https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_java/enterprise_pack_for_eclipse

Comment: Could you provide a link to the bug report?

Comment: The bug database is not public.